# What will the ERC20 converter use as an exchange rate?

Tags: erc20

Will it convert tokens based on ADA/ETH pair price at the moment of conversion? If so, which exchange will it use for knowing the rate of exchange?

Comment: Are you sure the ERC-20 converter can be used to swap tokens? My understanding is that it can be used to move the same token between the Ethereum network and the Cardano network.

Comment: I'm not sure, I only assumed. Good point. But then how would an ERC20 token benefit from the Cardano network advantages? This would give rise to many other questions.

Comment: For one thing, the ERC-20 could be an escape valve from the high gas fees on the Ethereum network if similar smart contracts on Cardano cost less to use.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that a good solution would be to provide an oracle that calculates the average price coming from different exchanges.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to me. Practical and appropriate Oracle application indeed. Though it would mean that the converter cannot function until it gets data feed from an Oracle first.